# C# ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework 6 throws error "Stored procedure not found"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've trawled through lots of similar questions and responses but couldn't find what I need so I'd appreciate any help.

I have the stored procedures in the database and it executes fine in SSMS.
It is in the model browser for the `.edmx`:

[image: Model Browser .edmx]

This is the code that throws the error.

```
private thisContext db = new thisContext();
var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var SelectFullProfile = true;

List<UsersSelectProfile_Result> profilelist = null;

profilelist = db.Database.SqlQuery<UsersSelectProfile_Result>(
"dbo.UsersSelectProfile @UserID={0}, @SelectFullProfile={1}",
UserId, SelectFullProfile).ToList();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does your MVC application have the right permissions? How are you authenticating?

Comment: Hi Kirsten. Thanks for your question. Yes the permissions are right. Using Windows authentication (integrated security=True). This problem only arose when I used the entity framework. A previous version of this application, which didn't use EF, works fine.

Comment: What connection string is EF being initialized with? I'd be looking to verify that the DbContext is actually pointing at the expected database. I.e. create a test table, entity, and entity config and verify that EF is reading/writing, then go to a test Sproc to see if there is some form of authorization issue on the DB.

Comment: does only one sp fail? perhaps try removing it and adding it back?

Comment: @Kirsten No it's any SP.

Comment: can you access the tables ok?

Comment: @Steve thanks for your suggestion. I did the following:
Created a new table and added one record.
Did "Update Model from Database" in the .edmx, new table was available and imported
Then tried 

    List<String> sText;
    sText = db.Database.SqlQuery<String>("SELECT sText FROM EFTest").ToList();

Which threw error "Invalid object name 'EFTest'"
Now I'm confused

Comment: @Kirsten I believe my response to #Steve covers yours as well

Comment: I mainly work with Code First these days ( it is so much easier ) so I am just guessing along. What if you try "SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database]; "   in the text of your query. Does it tell anything helpful?

Comment: It sounds like at runtime the application is being pointed at a different database/server. I don't believe the edmx alters connection strings in the web.config so I'd first check the web.config connection strings to see if it's being directed to a different database location.  Definitely seems weird though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was, as I suspected, all to do with the entity framework, although sorry I cannot pinpoint the issue.
I resolved it by regenerating the .edmx, I guess the first time left some corruption in the .edmx

And just for clarity, I didn't need to make any changes to the way I was calling the SPs at all.

I am very grateful to all those who were so forthcoming in their assistance

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ReadDataUsingStoredProcedure() example at 
[this project](https://github.com/entityframeworktutorial/EF6-DBFirst-Demo/blob/master/EF6DBFirstDemo/Program.cs)

referred to on [this tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/introduction.aspx)

I think your call should be something like

```
var profileList = db.UsersSelectProfile(0,1);
```

Comment: Hi Kirsten
Thanks again for replying.
I have tried this format as well, including hard-coding the parameters (as in your example) just for testing purposes. Unfortunately, no luck.
My instinct tells me that this is associated with the entity framework which I introduced, but since this functionality is new to me I'm still at a loss.

Comment: Thanks James
What does the following return ?
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<String>("SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database]")

Answer (score 0):

You were trying execute a query which was stored procedure. But you were missing a keyword like 'EXEC'. Just add the keyword 'EXEC' before your procedure name then try to execute. It should be work.

Comment: Thanks Abdul for your reply.
Actually I had the "EXEC" keyword before and it still didn't find the stored proc.
{Calling a SP without the "EXEC" is optionally correct SQL.}